# How to efficiently find a value inside nested objects using underscore's each function?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

In my game, I need find a certain monster that is contained in an "units" array. This array is inside a spatial cell structure inside a world object. How can I find this unit without writing ugly code?

```
var foundUnit = null;
_.each(worldHandler.world, function(zone) {
  if ( foundUnit ) return;
  _.each(zone, function(cellX) {
    if ( foundUnit ) return;
    _.each(cellX, function(cellY) {
      if ( foundUnit ) return;
      if ( !_.isUndefined(cellY.units) ) {
        _.each(cellY.units, function(unit) {
          if ( foundUnit ) return;

          if ( unit.id === id ) foundUnit = unit;
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
return foundUnit;
```

The trouble here is that I can't use return when I found the right value. Return inside the _.each() will just continue that current loop. Is there a better/cleaner way to find a certain value inside a nested object?

Example data:

```
{ // World
    '1': { // Zone
        '-1': { // Cell X
            '-1': { // Cell Y
                'units': []
            },
            '0': {
                'units': [{id:5}]
            },
            '1': {
                'units': []
            }               
        }
    } {
        '0': {
            '-1': {
                'units': []
            },
            '0': {
                'units': []
            },
            '1': {
                'units': []
            }   
        }
    } {
        '1': {
            '-1': {
                'units': []
            },
            '0': {
                'units': []
            },
            '1': {
                'units': []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your data.

Comment: You could use normal `for` or `for...in` loops instead ;)

Comment: i made http://danml.com/js/oquery.js to use css attrib-style queries for this sort of thing, you call like oQuery(worldHandler.world, "[id=123]") to find the units with the id of 123...

Comment: @dandavis Thanks, looks very interesting! Is it performant too?

Comment: @thg435 Just posted some example data!

Comment: @Nick: it's decent. i wrote to compete with taffyDB, and it's much faster than that... Is it faster than a single-use hand-coded iterator? i'd guess probably not, but maybe it's fast enough for your project.

Comment: @torazaburo done, sorry about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out `_.some`.

```
var foundUnit = null;
_.some(worldHandler.world, function(zone) {
    return _.some(zone, function(cellX) {
        return _.some(cellX, function(cellY) {
            return _.some(cellY.units, function(unit) {
                if ( unit.id === id ) {foundUnit = unit; return true; }
            });
        });
    });
});
return foundUnit;
```

Note that `_.some` no-ops if the object is null, so no need to check for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could flatten your nested structure into an array of units and then use `_.find` on it:

```
var zones = _.flatten(_.map(world, _.values));
var cells = _.flatten(_.map(zones, _.values));
var units = _.flatten(_.map(cells, _.values));
var unit = _.find(units, function(u) { return u.id == 7 });
```

If you're concerned about performance and you're looking up by `unit.id` then you should consider building an index:

```
var indexById = {};
_.each(units, function(u) {
    indexById[u.id] = u;
});
```

Then you can do constant time lookups: `var unit = indexById[7];`